# Callback for when loading finishes from Apollo Client + React?

Tags: react-apollo

Im using Apollo Client 2 with React. Is there a callback for when a query has finished loading?

Im making a user's account page. The email field should display the users email. I can get this value with my graphQL query but the loading only finishes after the component has already mounted. I therefore cant use componentDidMount. Is there callback or event I use to setState and populate the email field that way?

```
import React from 'react';
import gql from 'graphql-tag';
import { graphql } from 'react-apollo';

class AccountPage extends React.Component {
  render() {
    if (this.props.data.loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
    return(
    <form>
      <input type="email" />
    </form>
    )
  }
}

const UserQuery = gql`
    query UserQuery {
        user {
            _id
            email
        }
    }
`;

export default graphql(UserQuery)(AccountPage);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a neat way to get around that with [recompose](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose/blob/master/docs/API.md):

```
const LoadingComponent = () => <p>Loading...</p>

compose(
  // with compose, order matters -- we want our apollo HOC up top
  // so that the HOCs below it will have access to the data prop
  graphql(UserQuery),
  branch(
    ({ data }) => {
      return !data.user && data.loading
    },
    renderComponent(LoadingComponent)
  ),
  // BONUS: You can define componentDidMount like normal, or you can use
  // lifecycle HOC and make AccountPage a functional component :)
  lifecycle({
    componentDidMount() {
    // set your state here
    },
  }),
)(AccountPage)
```

`branch` will conditionally render whatever component you pass to it *instead of the wrapped component*. In this case, the wrapped component is everything below branch inside of compose. That means `AccountPage` is not mounted until `data.loading` is false and `data.user` is truthy, which lets us use componentDidMount to set the state based on the query result.